# How can I access the bands of a grib file with gdalwarp?

Tags: gdalwarp, grib

How can I access the subdatasets of a grib file? I am working with NLDAS data and I want to process only the first band of the grib file. I know how to do it with HDF data but I couldn't handle it with grib files. Any hints?

For example this one has 11 bands in it.

NLDAS_FORA0125_H.A20070702.1700.002.grb

I want to gdalwarp the first band of it which is temperature.

This is the gdalinfo output.

```
Driver: GRIB/GRIdded Binary (.grb)
Files: NLDAS_FORA0125_H.A20070702.1700.002.grb
Size is 464, 224
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",
    DATUM["unknown",
        SPHEROID["Sphere",6371200,0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]
Origin = (-125.000500000000002,53.000500000000002)
Pixel Size = (0.125000000000000,-0.125000000000000)

Corner Coordinates:

Upper Left  (-125.0005000,  53.0005000) (125d 0' 1.80"W, 53d 0' 1.80"N)
Lower Left  (-125.0005000,  25.0005000) (125d 0' 1.80"W, 25d 0' 1.80"N)
Upper Right ( -67.0005000,  53.0005000) ( 67d 0' 1.80"W, 53d 0' 1.80"N)
Lower Right ( -67.0005000,  25.0005000) ( 67d 0' 1.80"W, 25d 0' 1.80"N)
Center      ( -96.0005000,  39.0005000) ( 96d 0' 1.80"W, 39d 0' 1.80"N)

Band 1 Block=464x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined

  Description = 2[m] HTGL (Specified height level above ground)
  NoData Value=9999
  Metadata:
    GRIB_COMMENT=Temperature [K]
    GRIB_ELEMENT=TMP
    GRIB_FORECAST_SECONDS=0 sec
    GRIB_REF_TIME=  1183395600 sec UTC
    GRIB_SHORT_NAME=2-HTGL
    GRIB_UNIT=[K]
    GRIB_VALID_TIME=  1183395600 sec UTC
...
```

Comment: Tell us what gdalinfo reports for the file. Subdatasets need the "PREFIX:filename:etc" incantation, bands are specified with -b.

Comment: Please change the title of this question, as it is asking to access bands, not subdatasets.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 2):

That grib file does not have subdatasets, it has bands (in gdal terms). To access the first band with [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html), extract the first band with gdal_translate using a -b parameter, then use gdalwarp e.g.

```
gdal_translate -b 1 -of vrt NLDAS_FORA0125_H.A20070702.1700.002.grb NLDAS_FORA0125_H.A20070702.1700.002.vrt
gdalwarp NLDAS_FORA0125_H.A20070702.1700.002.vrt etc...
```